# Uninstalling a Helm chart dependency

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Kubernetes cluster where the application running within the cluster is managed by Helm. I have the following dependency in my `Chart.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: xyz
description: A Helm chart for the xyz application
type: application
version: 1.9.0
appVersion: 1.4.0
dependencies:
  - name: grafana
    repository: https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
    version: 6.58.6
```

and this installs Grafana fine as it should, when I run `helm install`. However, I no longer need Grafana in my cluster, so my question is how do I get rid of Grafana again (using Helm commands) once it has been installed?

I have tried to the remove the grafana section again from the dependency block in the `Chart.yaml`, but running `helm upgrade` does not remove Grafana from the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is not possible - I asked the same question on Slack, and the answer was:

*There is no current facility to decouple the lifecycle between a chart and its dependencies. You will need to uninstall the parent chart which will also remove the dependency*

(see https://app.slack.com/client/T09NY5SBT/C0NH30761/thread/C0NH30761-1694273955.452739)